# How do I trim my Japanese Maple to determine its shape?

Tags: pruning, tree-care

The tree was put in the ground about 6 years ago.  For the most part, I have let it grow with no interference; only trimming extra long branches.  I lost a middle branch growing upwards in year 2 due to freezing weather.  I would like it to eventually grow into a canopy over the grill, heat pump, and patio.

Do I let the tree grow as it does and wait until the upper canopy forms, before trimming the lower branches, or do I trim the lower branches now to encourage upwards growth?

[image]

Comment: Hmm, can I claim my own bounty?  I think I found a paper that provides the proper information.

Comment: You cannot do that. See this post on Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117244/331988. Full FAQ on the bounty system: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this information paper, I should begin trimming lower branches to shape the tree after 3-4 years, but no more than 25% per year.

https://www.arborday.org/trees/bulletins/documents/001-summary.pdf